# Cross-referencing trainstops in a simple train timetable database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I need to create a simple database for train timetables.

I will have a route table with all the routes for the trains. The route will be something like

```
 id | departure_station | arrival_station | time
```

But if departure_station is `B` and arrival station is `G` I have all the stations from `C` to `F` in between them and no way to sum up the time or let alone provide the user with the whole route.

My idea is to give every station a unique id and then retrieve all `departure_station` results that have the id>`B` and id<`G`, ordering them by `ID`, so the result would be `-C-D-E-F-`, but it seems this is not the easiest way to do it.

Being that an SQL database doesn't have the results in order, how can I refference `B` to `D`, then `D` to `E`, `E` to `F`  untill I reach `G` ?

EDIT:

Sample

```
traind_id | departs | arrives | route_id 
  1337       Iasi     Pascani      56


route_id | dep_station  |   arr_station | time
   56      Val. Lupului     Letcani       00:05
   56      Letcani          Tg. Frumos    00:10
   56      Tg. Frumos       Podu Iloaiei  00:20
   56      Podu Iloaiei     Motca         00:10
   56      Motca            Pascani       00:30
```

The Client wants to depart from `Letcani` and reach `Motca`. For that, I want to show him he can take train 1337 on route `Iasi-Pascani` and that
his stations will be `Letcani-Tg. Frumos-Podu Iloaiei-Motca` with total `route time = 00:10 + 00:20 + 00:10 = 00:40 minutes`.

But how do I select the stations in order and how do I know I can reach `Motca` from `Letcani` if the two stations are not connected in any way except for the intermediate stations in between them.

Comment: can you show some sample data from the table and the expected result?

Comment: @vkp I have edited my question.

Comment: Are the departure and arrival stations always on the same route?

Comment: @CL. Yes. The database has only simple liniar routes.

Answer (score 0):

First, find out if there are any matching routes, i.e., any routes that have both the departing and arrival stations:

```
SELECT route_id
FROM RouteStations AS R1
JOIN RouteStations AS R2 USING (route_id)
WHERE R1.dep_station = 'Letcani'
  AND R2.arr_station = 'Motca';
```

Then, for each such route, use a recursive [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) to fetch the stations:

```
WITH RECURSIVE steps(nr, dep, arr, time) AS (
  SELECT 1,
         dep_station,
         arr_station,
         time
  FROM RouteStations
  WHERE route_id = 56
    AND dep_station = 'Letcani'

  UNION ALL

  -- fetch the step that departs from the previous arrival station
  SELECT steps.nr + 1,
         RouteStations.dep_station,
         RouteStations.arr_station,
         RouteStations.time
  FROM RouteStations
  JOIN steps ON steps.arr_station = RouteStations.dep_station
  WHERE route_id = 56
    AND RouteStations.dep_station <> 'Motca'
)
SELECT *
FROM steps
ORDER BY nr;
```